# How to stop using AppCompat in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm new to Android development and I'm trying to follow Android development guide in Android Studio, specifically **trying to set up an action bar**.

My `minSdkVersion` is `15`, stated in `build:gradle`(Module:app) so I would think I wouldn't need to use any App Compatibility Support but my theme, as it says in `styles.xml` is  `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">` and **I can't change it to any Holo whitout crashing my app anytime I run it**.

Besides, using this one **I can't use `android:showAsAction`(it just doesnt work)** and instead need to use `app:showAsAction` and all the Android Support library.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us the specific problems you're stuck with, so we can help you with that. As it currently stands, your question is off-topic as per the help center.

Comment: if you don't want to support earlier versions of android then you won't need it. you can reconfigure the settings and should set min sdk support to the latest api you are using.

Comment: When I add a item in a menu xml and state android:showAsAction="ifRoom" it throws an error and says I should use app:showAsAction as I'm using appcompat library. But I don't want to use appcompat libraries. My min SDK version is API 15. I reseted all my project to make it 15 in the beginning.

Comment: You could remove the appcompat dependency from your build.gradle.. However it is recommended that you use the support library even though your minSdk is higher since they are updated and also contain bugfixes

Comment: Are you sure? In the android development lessons they say that as My min SDK version is high enough I shouldn't need to use them (although I do). If you are sure I will use them though.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

CommonsWare provided the correct steps but I still battled as there wasn't enough details for me to know exactly what to do (being new to Android Studio and Android development).

I found a blog post that explains the details here and it worked for me: https://mobiarch.wordpress.com/2015/04/17/removing-support-library-in-android-studio

Here is what it says (I have added some additional help):

Open build.gradle from your project. Locate the dependencies section.

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
}
```

Remove the line for the compatibility library. After that the section should look like this.

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

Save and close.

By default the app uses a theme that is available from the support library. This is not available from the core API. So we need to fix that. Open `res/values/styles.xml`. The style tag will look something like this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

Change the parent to a theme that is available from the core SDK. For example:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

Rename properties in the activity xml files such as `app:showAsAction` to `android:showAsAction`.

Extent your activity classes from `Activity` instead of `ActionBarActivity` and `AppCompatActivity`. You'll have to press Alt+Enter on `Activity` once you have made the changes to add import android.app.Activity at the top of the file. See the example below:

Change:

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;

public class DisplayMessageActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    .
    .
    .
}
```

to:

```
import android.app.Activity;

public class DisplayMessageActivity extends Activity {
    .
    .
    .
}
```

And the same for any other activities that extends `ActionBarActivity` and `AppCompatActivity`

Finally, perform a `Build | Clean Project` and a `Build | Rebuild Project` to sort out the current build errors.

Answer (score 7):

Step #1: Change your theme away from `Theme.AppCompat`

Step #2: Remove `appcompat-v7` from your list of `dependencies` in your `app` module's `build.gradle` file

Step #3: Change all activities to not inherit from `AppCompatActivity` or `ActionBarActivity`, but instead inherit from something else, like `Activity`

Step #4: Change all menu resources, replacing `app:` with `android:`

Step #5: Do a clean rebuild (Build > Clean Project) and fix any lingering compilation errors triggered by the above four steps

[Here is a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ActionBar/ActionBarDemoNative) that uses the native action bar.

Comment: Why doesn't the template Android Studio creates come with all that? As I move on doing the android development lessons I notice a lot of things they say I should be able to call like **getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);**" crashes my app. Instead I need to use **getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);** although (don't know why) I have the up option defined without having to set it up

Comment: @JoaquimFerrer: "Why doesn't the template Android Studio creates come with all that?" -- actually, it does, if you create the project with a `minSdkVersion` of 22, at least in Android Studio 1.2.2. You then have to manually reset the `minSdkVersion` to your desired value. However, the behavior of the new-project/new-activity templates varies by Android Studio version. "I should be able to call like getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); crashes my app" -- that should not compile if you are not using `appcompat-v7`. Use `getActionBar()` instead of `getSupportActionBar()`.

Comment: It was the opposite functions sorry(I already edited). But yes I'm using the lattest Android Studio but in the creation of the project I made my `minSdk` 15 and not 22. Do you think I should use  the appcompat libraries?

Comment: @JoaquimFerrer: "Do you think I should use the appcompat libraries?" -- with a `minSdkVersion` of 15, their use is not required. Some other things in Android, like the Android Design Support Library, require you to use `appcompat-v7`. On the other hand, it has many more bugs than does the native implementation. It also forces a bit of the Material Design aesthetic on you -- your action bar on Android 4.x will not look like the native action bar. Whether this is a good thing (consistency in your app UI across versions) or not (inconsistency with other apps on the device) is up to you.

Comment: Ok I will update it then to native version. As to change the theme: I tried changing the theme to  `<style name="CustomActionBarTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar"> ` but it didn't recognize it as I don't have it in my project folder. What theme should I change to? Do I have to download it?  I'm sorry for all the questions but I'm really newby at android or any other graphical development so thank you very much for the pacience.

Comment: @JoaquimFerrer: "it didn't recognize it" -- Sorry, but I do not know what either of the "it" instances in that phrase refer to. [Here is another sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ActionBar/VersionedColor) where I use `@android:style/Theme.Holo` as the base for Android 4.x and I use `@android:style/Theme.Material` as the base for Android 5.0+.

Comment: Android studio recognized the theme. But yes I will use that project. Thanks :)