# Usage of support library views with material theme

Tags: android

When I include views which are available only in support library (FAB , coordinator layout) in my layout, it throws an exception and asks me to use an AppCompat theme. But as my apps min. Sdk is 21 , I am using a Material theme and don't want to change it to AppCompat. What to do in this situation ?

Comment: AppCompt v21 is material design, are we able to see code to make sure your implementing the widgets correctly?

Answer (score 0):

[How to stop using AppCompat in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31338881/how-to-stop-using-appcompat-in-android-studio)

This should be the solution for your problem
But be aware that you can't use app:… in xml, you have to use android:… if possible

And you can't use Constraint layout I think.
Why do you want to avoid AppCombat?

Comment: It's an inflate exception caused by not using an appcompat theme