# Android App Takes More Space Then APK Size

Tags: android, google-play

I made a small app with my father and we released it to the google play store, after downloading it onto my phone i find out that the app is taking 13.5MB (apk size is 4.5mb or around 5mb full size)

where is the extra space coming from and is there any way to make it smaller?

I already tried making the classes.dex smaller by using minifyenabled but that just seems to crash the app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ... is there any way to make it smaller?
>
> I already tried making the classes.dex smaller by using minifyenabled but that just seems to crash the app.

Here is my 2 cents. There can be multiple ways to reduce the size.

1. You can use `minifyEnabled` as you mentioned. However you'll need to
   specify to ProGuard to exclude some files in the ProGuard config
   file. Quoting from documentation of [Shrink Your
   Code](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code#shrink-code):

   > To enable code shrinking with ProGuard, you'll need to add `minifyEnabled true` to the appropriate build type in your
   >   build.gradle file.
   >   However, it's important that you do enable code shrinking on your final APK used for testing, because **it might introduce bugs if you
   >   do not sufficiently customize which code to keep.**

   Quoting from [Customize which code to
   keep](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code#keep-code)
   section on the same documentation on which files to keep:

   > For some situations, the default ProGuard configuration file (proguard-android.txt) is sufficient and ProGuard removes all—and
   >   only—the unused code. However, many situations are difficult for
   >   ProGuard to analyze correctly and it might remove code your app
   >   actually needs. Some examples of when it might incorrectly remove
   >   code include:
   >
   > - When your app references a class only from the AndroidManifest.xml    file
   > - When your app calls a method from the Java Native Interface    (JNI)
   > - When your app manipulates code at runtime (such as with    reflection or introspection)
2. You can use recent release of [App Bundles](https://developer.android.com/platform/technology/app-bundle/) to reduce the size. Eg: Instead of installing your apk containing all the assets for all densities `hdpi`, `xhdpi`, it will dynamically only include the assets required for the specific device, thus reducing the size of the app by quite a bit. From the docs:

   > Further reduce the size of your app by installing only the features that the majority of your audience use. And then, with Dynamic Delivery, users can download and install dynamic features when they’re needed.

Answer (score 0):

Similar question [how to bring Hello World Android app size down](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53367716/295004) which if you read the comments leads to this: [How to stop using AppCompat in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31338881/295004)

So depending on your minimum SDK level you should look into removing AppCompat library if your goal is to make your app as small as possible.